# SystemJS not sending cookies in Safari when loading bundles dynamically

Tags: angular, angular8, systemjs

I'm trying to load modules dynamically in my angular app using SystemJS from an endpoint which is specified by me. The app uses authentication and sets the auth-token as a cookie in the browser.

This seems to work perfectly fine in Chrome and Firefox. With each request being done from SystemJS, the cookie get's automatically set and everything works fine, modules get loaded! However, this is not the case with Safari. Somehow, cookies are being ignored in these custom requests.

My code:

```
    private readonly systemJs: typeof System;

    ...

    private method() {
       this.systemJs = (window as any)["System"];
       this.systemJs.import(DYNAMIC_URL)
           .then(...)
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, do you have any progress? I am facing the same issue when loading dynamic module in safari but the request doesn't bring on the cookie.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with older Chromes. Updating SystemJS to v6.4.1 (removed anonymous crossorigin for same domain) helped to send requests with auth cookie.